# Комментарии и вывод их через форму Django

Tags: django, post

Пытаюсь сделать вывод новости с привязанными комментариями и возможностью оставить комментарий через форму. У меня получилось сделать вывод новости и комментарии к ним, но я не могу понять как сделать форму для того что бы оставлять комментарии, чтобы все это было на 1 странице.

Я пытался сделать отдельное представление и добавить еще `url` такой же только с другим представлением, но понял что это так не работает. Я новичок и только начал изучать `Django`, надеюсь натолкнете на правильный путь.

Вот мой код:

```py
# model.py

class Comment(models.Model):
    news = models.ForeignKey(News, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tittle = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='название')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name="текс комментария")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tittle

    class Meta:   # класс для изменения название самой таблички
        verbose_name = "Комментарий"
        verbose_name_plural = "Комментарии"

class News(models.Model):
    tittle = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Статья')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='текст статьи')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Время обновления')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Фото', blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tittle

    class Meta:   # класс для изменения название самой таблички
        verbose_name = "Новость"
        verbose_name_plural = "Новости"
```

```
# views.py

class NewsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'main/news_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'news'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(NewsDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        news_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        context['comment'] = Comment.objects.filter(news=news_pk)
        return context
```

```py
# urls.py

    path('<int:pk>', views.NewsDetailView.as_view(), name='news_detail')
```

```html
{# news_detail.html #}

{% block content %}
    <div class="features">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <h1>{{ news.tittle }}</h1>
        <p>{{ news.content }}</p>
        <p>{{ news.created_at }}</p>
        <p>{{ news.category }}</p>
        </div>

        {% for el in comment %}
               <div class="alert alert-warning">
               <p>{{ el.text }}</p>
               <p>{{ el.created_at }}</p>
               </div>
        {% endfor %}
    <div class="features">
        <h1>Добавление комментария</h1>
        <form method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}<br>
            {{ form.tittle }}<br>
            {{ form.text }}<br>
            <span>{{ error }}</span>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Добавить комментарий</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

В `views` надо поменять наследование на `TemplateView` и указать `get` и `post`. `DetailView` не умеет работать с `post`.

`get` - показываешь страницу

`post` - получаешь `self.request.POST` из формы `<form method="post">` и передаешь в модель формы `CommentForm`. Проверяешь на валидность `is_valid()` и редирект на нужную страницу или возвращаешь на форму показывая, что ошибка ввода данных.

**views**

```
class NewsDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main/news_detail.html'


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        news_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        context['comment'] = Comment.objects.filter(news=news_pk)
        context.update({'CommentForm': CommentForm}) #передаем форму из forms.py
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()        
        news_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        formPost = CommentForm(self.request.POST)   
        if formPost.is_valid():            
            form_update = formPost.save(commit=False)
            form_update.save()            
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('news_detail', args=(news_pk,)))
        else:
            print('NotValid')  
            context['comment'] = Comment.objects.filter(news=news_pk)
            context.update({'CommentForm': formPost})
            return self.render_to_response(context)
```

**html**

```
   <form action="{% url {{ pk }} %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ CommentForm.non_field_errors }}
        {{ CommentForm }}
        <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
    </form>
```

код не тестил, могут быть какие-то синтаксические ошибки, но логика такая